# need to display graph values in a PPTX document

Tags: python, python-pptx

This code works but the values are NOT displayed in the embedded graph. What am I doing wrong? The graph is there, but no labels. How can I set it to display the values?
[image]

```
from pptx import Presentation

from pptx.chart.data import ChartData, CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE, XL_LEGEND_POSITION, XL_LABEL_POSITION
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[6])  # blank slide

chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['Yes','No']
chart_data.add_series('Test', [.45,.55])   

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(8), Inches(6)

chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.DOUGHNUT, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart
chart.plots[0].has_data_labels = True   # OK
chart.legend.position = XL_LEGEND_POSITION.BOTTOM

data_labels = chart.plots[0].data_labels
data_labels.number_format = '0.1%'     # doesn't show up
data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END

fill = data_labels.font.fill
fill.solid()
data_labels.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)   # not showing

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
chart.plots[0].data_labels.show_percentage = True
```

Described along with its brethren in the documentation here:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/chart.html#pptx.chart.datalabel.DataLabels

Comment: Excellent. You the man! Is the project dormant? Needs a bit of documentation for sure.

Comment: Actually, not only does that not work but it breaks down the PPT. When I try to open it, I get the classic "Powerpoint will attempt to repair this file", to no avail.

Comment: Try getting rid of all the other lines after the add chart (other than `prs.save()` and only put this one and see how it goes. Then you can build up from there. If that still produces a problem you can open an issue on the GitHub issue list and I'll take a look.